# Slack request signing verification failed in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

I am trying to setup slack bot and facing below issue.

Error: Slack request signing verification failed

I am exactly following this YT tutorial, even tried git clone his repo to try out but still facing same error.

I even tried to search other slack bot setup tutorial and come back to same issue.

Please help if any of you have experience in fixing this.

Followed tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Awuh2I6iFb0

**-> Environment:** NodeJS

**-> app.js file**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api');
const { createEventAdapter } = require('@slack/events-api');

const slackSigningSecret = process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET;
const slackToken = process.env.SLACK_TOKEN;
const port = process.env.SLACK_PORT || 3000;

const slackEvents = createEventAdapter(slackSigningSecret);
const slackClient = new WebClient(slackToken);


slackEvents.on('app_mention', (event) => {
  console.log(`Got message from user ${event.user}: ${event.text}`);
  (async () => {
    try {
      await slackClient.chat.postMessage({ channel: event.channel, text: `Hello <@${event.user}>! :tada:` })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.data)
    }
  })();
});

slackEvents.on('error', console.error);

slackEvents.start(port).then(() => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`)
});
```

Full error code:
Error: Slack request signing verification failed
at Server. (/Users/byao/CD/playground/slackcicd/node_modules/@slack/events-api/dist/http-handler.js:148:39)
at Server.emit (events.js:375:28)
at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:897:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17) {
code: 'SLACKHTTPHANDLER_REQUEST_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILURE'
}

Very appreciated and full of thank you if any of you are willing to help!

Comment: Seems like a similar issue has been posted in the repo. Hopefully that helps! https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/972

Comment: Yes, i read that too! The issue closed without solution :(

Comment: Hmm. If you are 100% sure you are using the correct signing secret then I might also suggest creating a new app and using that app's credentials instead, maybe that makes a difference? Otherwise I'd recommend maybe using the Bolt Js framework instead, I find it easier to use :) https://slack.dev/bolt-js/tutorial/getting-started

Comment: Good idea, thanks for your sharing!